# Would it be correct to interpret $\hat{A} V \neq \hat{A} \hat{V}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, potential-energy, commutator

Define $V=V(\mathbf{r})$ as the potential function, $\hat{A}$ is some differential operator, then for an arbitrary function $\psi$
$$\hat{A} \hat{V} \psi \iff \partial (V\psi)
$$

whereas $$\hat{A} V\psi \iff (\partial V)\psi$$
therefore $$\hat{A} \hat{V}  \neq \hat{A} V$$
An example would be the commutation relation between the potential function and angular momentum in the x direction:
$$\hat{L_x}=\hat{y}\hat{p}_z-\hat{z}\hat{p_y}$$
then
$$[\hat{V},\hat{L_x}]=i \hbar(y \partial_z V-z\partial_yV)=-(y \hat{p_z}V-z\hat{p_y}V)$$
That is if $-(y \hat{p_z}V-z\hat{p_y}V)=\hat{L_x}\hat{V}$, $\hat{V}\hat{L_x}=0$ which is not true in general, therefore it should instead be written that $-(y \hat{p_z}V-z\hat{p_y}V)=\hat{L_x}V \neq \hat{L_x} \hat{V}$ (because operating on $\psi $ will give different results) ?

Comment: I'm getting far too many downvotes. Please explain why is my question so poor?

Comment: IMO, your symbols are not well-defined and it is totally unclear what your question is. What is $\hat V$ in contrast to $V$? Why in the second formula the derivative acts only on $V$ and not on $V\psi$?! So please elaborate and state clearly what your question is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working in the coordinate representation, so the  carets are superfluous. It is conceivable you just want reassurance that Heaviside [symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_calculus) act on everything to their right, that is
$$∂~~~~≡∂()+∂=(∂)+(∂)+∂,$$
where $(∂)\equiv ~'$,  $(∂)\equiv ~'$, and an arbitrary placeholder function *f(x)* acted upon is always implied  on the right.

Often, depending on circumstances,  *f=1*, in which case the free-dangling rightmost derivative ∂ is eliminated. Is this your question?